# Export WebGrid data to Excel in MVC4

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I want to export WebGrid data to excel with formatting.

I have written below code which export WebGrid data to Excel.

```
 WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: listReport, canPage: false, canSort: false);

        string gridData = grid.GetHtml(
            columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("ID", "ID"),
                    grid.Column("Name", "Name"),
                    grid.Column("Summary", "Summary"),
                    grid.Column("Detail", "Detail"),
                    grid.Column("ProjectName", "Project Name")
                    )
                ).ToString();


        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=CustomerInfo.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        Response.Write(gridData);
        Response.End();
```

I want to do formatting in excel.
Is it possible to export data with formatting?

Also it gives me below error when i open the generated excel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually created an Excel file. You've created an HTML file masquerading as an Excel 2003 file, which is a bad idea. I explain why and cover some alternatives on [my blog](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net).

Styling will be difficult, because of the way you're creating the source HTML. You could parse it with a library, then add basic styling via each elements `style` attribute. Or instead of using WebGrid you can manually build your HTML.

```
string html = "<table style='color:red'><tr><td>Hello, world!</td></tr></table>";
```

But really, the best thing to do is generate real Excel files. Here's a quick excerpt from my blog using EPPlus. It's shown in Web Forms. In MVC you'd actually want to return a `FileResult` rather than writing directly to the response.

```
protected void ExportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myexcelfile.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    var package = new ExcelPackage(); //create a new package, this is the equivalent of an XLSX file.
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Data"); //Add a new sheet to the workbook
    var dt = GetDataTable(); //This retrieves a System.Data.DataTable, you'd likely get it from your database.
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true); //EPPlus contains helper function to load data from a DataTable, though you could manually fill in rows/column values yourself if you want
    var range = sheet.Cells[1, 1, dt.Rows.Count + 1, 2]; //We're getting a reference to all the cells that contain data
    var table = sheet.Tables.Add(range, "My Data Table"); //Creating an Excel table
    table.TableStyle = TableStyles.Medium8; //Setting the table style to something that looks nice
    range.AutoFitColumns(); //Auto fitting the column widths.
    Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```